# django ordering with greek characters

Tags: django

in my django application admin i have the names of my administrators listed and ordered by name.
However the alphabetical ordering does not seem to work correctly. I am not sure if thats because of the greek characters.

Here's what happens:

- Names starting with the character A
- then a name starting with the character Z
- B,Γ,Δ,Ε... etc (ordering continues normally)

here's my class: (striped down from models.py)

```
class Admin(models.Model):
    admin_name = models.CharField(unique = True, blank = False, null = False, max_length = 128, verbose_name = u'admin full name')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.admin_name
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('admin_name',)
        verbose_name = u'Admin Info'
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: i use mysql and you are right because when i sort the names using mysql workbench the same thing happens. But in another table where i store client names in a field, ordering works as expected so I cant tell why it doesnt work in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Django, but is the responsibility of your database engine. Databases have a setting called 'collation', which determines how characters are sorted. For instance, for MySQL you probably want the `greek_general_ci` collation.